# Accessing a list from a different fragment

Tags: java, android

So I have my `MainActivity.java`, I also have a `FragmentA.java` and a `FragmentB.java`.

In my `MainActivity` I have a `BottomNavigation` which allows me to switch between the two fragments.

**MainActivity.java**

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        Fragment selectedFragment = null;
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_a:
                selectedFragment = new FragmentA();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_b:
                selectedFragment = new FragmentB();
                break;
        }

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment).commit();

        return true;
    }
};
```

Inside `FragmentA` I have a `RecyclerView` with an adapter of course and on each `CardView` there is a button, when i click that button i want to pass the corresponding object to the `RecyclerView` in `FragmentB`.

**FragmentA.java**

```
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new RewardItemAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        //When I click the item, pass theItem to FragmentB
        CustomObject theItem = items.get(position);
    }
});
```

**FragmentB.java**

```
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
            itemsList = new ArrayList<>();
            itemsList.add(new CustomObject(R.drawable.picture, "Text", "More text.", 200));


//I'm guessing I want to add the CustomObject that I clicked to the list here so that I can display it in the RecyclerView

            recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.fragmentBRecyclerView);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
            adapter = new FragmentBItemAdapter(itemsList);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            return v;
        }
```

The only issue is I have no idea how to, I tried using Interfaces but I couldn't implement it properly, I'm not sure if it's because I am instantiating a new instance of the fragments.

Comment: The ["official Android wisdom"](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating) says _" All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done either through a shared ViewModel or through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly."_ So, you could just route everything through the Activity. With or without a ViewModel.

Comment: You'll need to implement an `interface` for each `Fragment`. Its a good practice as `Fragments` should never talk to each other directly and instead should use the host `Activity` as a medium; `MainActivity` should handle the data transfers using the interfaces provided by `FragmentA` and `FragmentB` [See this answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43072336/android-pass-edit-text-element-value-between-tabbed-fragments) as it is very similar to your problem.

Comment: look at this: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#CommunicatingWithActivity this is exactly what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by two ways:

1) Through Interface Contract between the Fragment and Activity

```
class FragmentA: Fragment() {
    interface SomeInterfaceName {
        fun setSelectedItem(item: SomeItem)
    }
}

class FragmentA: Fragment() {
    interface AnotherInterfaceName {
        fun getSelectedItem(): SomeItem
    }
}

class ContainerActivity: Activity(), AnotherInterfaceName, SomeInterfaceName {
   var someItem: SomeItem? = null

    fun setSelectedItem(item: SomeItem) {
        someItem = item
        // inflate your FragmentB
    }     

    fun getSelectedItem(): SomeItem {
        return someItem;
    }
}
```

But the best solution in my opinion is to use a shared [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel) for this case.

You can read about this he [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?gclid=CjwKCAiA767jBRBqEiwAGdAOr40bSSsj1tokxFRS-czhgSnPeRDZkyWDmMlrnPebfbygnTXDZgqe4BoC4psQAvD_BwE) under "Share data between fragments" section.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the job by interface is correct, But you have to bind it to the Fragment in the onAttached lifeCycle method.

Define an Interface. **OnFragmentInteractionListener.java**

```
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(String args);
}
```

Then Implement your activity with the interface.

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnFragmentInteractionListener{

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        @Override
        onFragmentInteraction(String args){
            **// Made the Change Here**
            // Send Local Broadcast Receiver 
            Intent intent = new Intent("UPDATE_LIST");
            intent.putExtra("TYPE", 0);
            // Change the args to get position or the relevant param
            intent.putExtra("POSITION", selectedPosition);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
   }
```

In the **FragmentA.java**,

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
    OnFragmentInteractionListener mCallback;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    ...

    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new RewardItemAdapter.OnItemClickListener() 
    {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(int position) {
       //When I click the item, pass theItem to FragmentB
            CustomObject theItem = items.get(position);
            // Send the selected Item Name to Main Activity through args
            mCallback.onFragmentInteraction(theItem.getName);
       }
    });

}
```

On your **FragmentB.java** class add Local Broadcast Receiver

public class FragmentBt extends Fragment{

```
    public static Fragment newInstance(){
       ...
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, container, false);
        return v;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Register Local Broadcast Receiver
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("UPDATE_LIST"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Destroy the  Local Broadcast Receiver
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
    }

    // Create Broadcast Receiver instance
    private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(intent.hasExtra("POSITION")){
                mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(intent.getIntExtra("POSITION", 0));
                // Update Adapter as the requirement
            }
        }
    };

}
```

Hope this will help.
Cheers!!

Comment: Nice! Just a quick question, regarding `((FragmentB)fragment.updateRecyclerView();` how would I use `UpdateRecycleView();` since it doesnt know of the item within the other fragment?

Comment: I suppose I could create a method that takes the item it returns as a parameter and feed it through there.

Comment: `if (fragment instanceof FragmentB){` returns false so it can't reach `((FragmentB) fragment).UpdateView();`, I am clicking the button in FragmentA so it's not a instanceof FragmentB

Comment: I got the point @MarkDenom, So (fragment instanceof FragmentB) returns false since you are in the FragmentA, 

So that use LocalBroadcast Receiver. I'll edit the answer

Comment: @MarkDenom Hope the answer help. Plz check the Edit on Activity  onFragmentInteraction override method.

Comment: Hi! I just woke up and got on, I shall test it out :-)

Comment: It sends the item but when I try to update it just goes back to one item, I think this is because when I click the BottomNavigationMenu it initializes a new instance of the FragmentB so it gets cleared everytime